# UWP Push notification stop working if built from another machine

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am implementing push notifications in our Xamarin.Forms application.
What I have followed is this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push
Android and iOS are working perfectly as intended, my problem is with the UWP Push notification.
I have used Visual Studio to associate the application with the store, and I took the Package SID and the Application Secret and added them to the Notification hub in Azure like shown in the documentation linked above. I tried to run the application, and I was able to receive the notification. Perfect!
**Problem that my team and myself faced is the next**: When one of my colleagues pulled the source code to test it, the notification was never received. Even when we install the application from our build server the same problem is faced.
**Why does the notification stop working when built from another machine than mine, and how to fix it so that it will keep working when built from any other machine?**

Comment: Perhaps go over MS's guide on troubleshooting Push Notification issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was able to fix it by changing the certificate we were using, then after checking the link you gave me it showed all the WNS authorization errors. So it could have helped if I saw it before :)

Comment: Glad you resolved it. Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it? That way this post does not show up in searches for unresolved questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be simple, steps I taken to fix the problem are the next:
After associating the application and reserve it in the windows store, I got a publisher name: `CN=********-****-****-****-************`, in Visual Studio, I right clicked on the:
 UWP Project -> Application -> Package Manifest -> Packaging,
 and you can find the publisher name right to the `Publisher` label, and right next to that there's a `Choose Certificate...` button. I clicked it and chose `Configure Certificate` drop down list and clicked on `Create Test Certificate`.
Three text boxes should be entered, publisher common name, and password and its confirmation. Inside the Publisher Common Name I entered the `********-****-****-****-************` without the `CN=` and entered my password. After creating the certificate I installed it on others laptops that needs to build the application and notification was working after.